# What is wrong this method?

Tags: c#, winforms, list, methods

Why I am getting this error at LIST: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property...

```
       List<string> LIST = new List<string>(); 

       public static void GDT(RichTextBox ResultRTB1)
        {
            foreach (string Items in LIST)
            {
                //do something
            }

        }
```

Comment: LIST variable has to be static as well

Comment: Could someone please improve his title as well?

Comment: You probably want to learn more about the concept of class and instance members. Try it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645629(v=vs.71).aspx . If you think it is old, it does not matter, it still applies.

Answer (score 2):

The variable LIST is declared without the static keyword. In this way is considered an instance member of the including class. A static method like your GDT cannot use the instance members of the class without declaring an instance of the class. 
You could resolve your problem declaring

```
static List<string> LIST = new List<string>();
```

or removing the static keyword from the GDT  method, but without knowing the context in which you are using this method and this variable is not possible to give an advice

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 private static List<string> LIST = new List<string>();
```

You get an error because you cannot access instance members inside the static methods. You need an object instance to access it.

Or try this

```
public static void GDT(RichTextBox ResultRTB1)
{
    YourType instance = new YourType();
    foreach (string Items in instance.LIST)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to refer an instance member inside a static method, either declare your list as static, or create a class instance inside your method and then access the list from there.